# Run python script when a button is clicked in dash

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I'm developing a multi page dashboard using python Dash . On the main page I have created a layout that has an 'Submit' button . So when the user selects options and clicks the Submit button it should call another .py script and should display that on the same page .

Index.py is the main program
Layout.py has the layouts
new1.py has the layout that has 'Submit Button'
new2.py is the script that needs to be displayed on clicking the submit button

Here is the code in new1.py where I have declared button

```
html.Button('Clear',id='clear_button', n_clicks=0,  style = { 'width' : '30%', 'margin-top': '15vw', "margin":"15px" ,'border-radius': '8px'}),
```

Index.py that has the call back for button

```
@app.callback(
   dash.dependencies.Output('apply_button', 'children'),
   [dash.dependencies.Input('button', 'n_clicks')])
def run_script_onClick(n_clicks):
  
   if not n_clicks:
       raise PreventUpdate
       
       script_path = 'python new2.py'

      call(["python3", script_path])
    
       
   
      return output_content
```

Is this correct   ? When I click the Apply button nothing is coming. I want the output of the new2.py to be displayed on the same screen. Also where should i give the call back statement . In Index.py or in the new1.py ? Can someone help pls.

Thanks,
Prathap

Comment: you use `output_content` but you never create it - so you should get error message. Maybe you would need something like `output_content = call(...)` But maybe it would be better to `import` code from `new2.py` and execute it as normal code - but it would need to keep code in function in `new2.py`

Comment: maybe yoi should first use `print()` to see to see if function was executed and what you get in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`.

Comment: if you use `script_path = 'python new2.py'` then finally you run code `call(["python3", "python new2.py"])` which is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Function `os.system()` sends text directly on screen (to console) and it returns only `error code` (number `0` means `OK`) so you can't assign this text to variable or send with `return`. if you use `subprocess.call()` then you have the same problem. You need other functions from module `subprocess` - ie. `subprocess.run()` or `subprocess.check_output()`

In some situations you may need to use full path to Python - ie. when you run it without `shell=True`. Sometimes it is good also to use full path to script because code may runs in different folder then you expect - you may check `Current Working directory` with `print( os.getcwd() )`

---

This is minimal working code for me on Linux.

I removed `style` because it not important in this problem and I don't use `from ... import ...` to show which commands are from `subprocess` and which from `dash`.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import subprocess

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
                       html.Div([            
                       html.Button('Apply', id='apply-button', n_clicks=0),
                       html.Div(id='output-container-button', children='Hit the button to update.')
                      ])
                ])                      
                
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('apply-button', 'n_clicks')])
def run_script_onClick(n_clicks):
    #print('[DEBUG] n_clicks:', n_clicks)
    
    if not n_clicks:
        #raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
        return dash.no_update

    # without `shell` it needs list ['/full/path/python', 'script.py']           
    #result = subprocess.check_output( ['/usr/bin/python', 'script.py'] )  

    # with `shell` it needs string 'python script.py'
    result = subprocess.check_output('python script.py', shell=True)  

    # convert bytes to string
    result = result.decode()  
    
    return result
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=8080, debug=True)
```

**script.py**

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to create multipage then you should use `import` to load code, run it and create new layout object - like in https://dash.plotly.com/urls

Using `subprocess` you can only create string with HTML but not layout object.